# How do you delete wild card cookies in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you delete a cookie in rails that was set with a wild card domain:

```
cookies[:foo] = {:value => 'bar', :domain => '.acme.com'}
```

When, following the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Cookies.html"docs"), you do:

```
cookies.delete :foo
```

the logs say

```
Cookie set: foo=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

Notice that the domain is missing (it seems to use the default 
params for everything).  Respecting the RFC, of course the cookie's 
still there, Browser -> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> ->

```
javascript:alert(document.cookie);
```

Voilà!

Q: What's the "correct" way to delete such a cookie?

Comment: Thx! that works like a charm ... also i tried to add  link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Cookies.html "docs" but that may have failed

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pass the :domain on delete as well. Here's the source of that method:

```
# Removes the cookie on the client machine by setting the value to an empty string
# and setting its expiration date into the past.  Like []=, you can pass in an options
# hash to delete cookies with extra data such as a +path+.
def delete(name, options = {})
  options.stringify_keys!
  set_cookie(options.merge("name" => name.to_s, "value" => "", "expires" => Time.at(0)))
end
```

As you can see, it just sets an empty cookie with the name you gave, set to expire in 1969, and with no contents. But it does merge in any other options you give, so you can do:

```
cookies.delete :foo, :domain => '.acme.com'
```

And you're set.